# How to replace a string with a string containing slash with sed?

Tags: sed

I am looking for a way to replace a string in a file with a string that contains a slash by using sed.

```
connect="192.168.100.61/foo"
srcText="foo.bar=XPLACEHOLDERX"
echo $srcText | sed "s/XPLACEHOLDERX/$connect"
```

The result is:

```
sed: -e Expression #1, Character 32: Unknown option for `s'
```

Comment: A more generalized version: [How to search & replace arbitrary literal strings in `sed` and `awk` (and perl)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54059656/3960947).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use another character as delimiter in the `s` command:

```
printf '%s\n' "$srcText" | sed "s|XPLACEHOLDERX|$connect|"
```

Or escape the slashes with ksh93's `${var//pattern/replacement}` parameter expansion operator (now also supported by `zsh`, `bash`, `mksh`, `yash` and recent versions of busybox `sh`).

```
printf '%s\n' "$srcText" | sed "s/XPLACEHOLDERX/${connect//\//\\/}/"
```

Comment: +1 for second way. first one does not work on freebsd.

Comment: I know it's not the question, but what if the string contains a backslash, perhaps followed by an 'n'....and you don't want it replaced by a single newline character?

Comment: @MaxWaterman, if I understand you correctly, that backslash is in the $connect string, right? Then you have to escape it before reaching `sed`: `printf '%s\n' "$srcText" | sed "s|XPLACEHOLDERX|${connect//\\/\\\\}|"`

Answer (score 3):

If your shell supports it:

```
"${srcText/XPLACEHOLDERX/$connect}"
```