# Sed find and replace with slashes

Tags: shell-script, sed, scripting

I am having trouble using sed find/replace with slashes in the find parameter.

Sample contents of test.sh

```
str=$(sed -n '/^user:/p' /tmp/shadowtest) # find "user:" line in /etc/shadowtest
arr=(${str//:/ }) # explode str with : as delimeter
arr=${arr[1]} # grab the 2nd element
sed -i 's|$arr|XXXXX|g' /tmp/shadowtest # Nothing gets replaced in shadowtest
```

Sample contents of /tmp/shadowtest

```
# junk here
user:$6$hcwp49Lr$BjcJYc/nwaufmsOIw4Tw/POaXO4j.0HDLU0:16310:0:99999:7:::
# junk here
```

When I run the script as is, nothing gets replaced in the shadowtest file. But if I change the sed command to something like

```
sed -i 's|99999|XXXXX|g' /tmp/shadowtest
```

it works fine.

Comment: Your using pipe symbols, they should be slashes when your using sed

Comment: The pipe works [via](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39800/how-to-replace-a-string-with-a-string-containing-slash-with-sed)

Comment: Look at AProgrammer's answer and try using double quotes instead. He beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $arr to be substituted, you need to put it outside single quotes.  For instance:

```
sed -i "s|$arr|XXXXX|g" /tmp/shadowtest
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the purpose of your code correctly, then, in your example case:

```
$6$hcwp49Lr$BjcJYc/nwaufmsOIw4Tw/POaXO4j.0HDLU0
```

should be replaced with:

```
XXXXX
```

If this is true, you don't need to involve the shell at all:

```
sed '/^user:/s/:[^:]*/:XXXXX/
' <<\DATA
# junk here
user:$6$hcwp49Lr$BjcJYc/nwaufmsOIw4Tw/POaXO4j.0HDLU0:16310:0:99999:7:::
other:$6$hcwp49Lr$BjcJYc/nwaufmsOIw4Tw/POaXO4j.0HDLU0:16310:0:99999:7:::
user:different stuff in this spot:16310:0:99999:7:::
# junk here
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
# junk here
user:XXXXX:16310:0:99999:7:::
other:$6$hcwp49Lr$BjcJYc/nwaufmsOIw4Tw/POaXO4j.0HDLU0:16310:0:99999:7:::
user:XXXXX:16310:0:99999:7:::
# junk here
```

It works in the same way your own does - mostly - in that it addresses only lines that begin with the string `user:`, but, rather than performing the `p` function on them, it does the `s///` function instead.

It substitutes the string `:XXXXX` for the first sequence of non-`:` characters immediately preceded by a `:` on lines that begin with the string `user:`.