# I am not able to update a variable through sed command

Tags: linux, sed, grep, cat, replace

I have assigned two variables but not able to update

```
x=$(cat /scratch/env.properties | grep ConfigPath)
y=$(ConfigPath=/scratch/a/b)
```

then sed to replace ConfigPath in env.properties

```
sed 's/$x/$y/' env.properties
```

This is not updating ConfigPath in env.properties as assigned in $y

Comment: See [How can I use variables in the LHS and RHS of a sed substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/how-can-i-use-variables-in-the-lhs-and-rhs-of-a-sed-substitution) and [Sed find and replace with slashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152817/sed-find-and-replace-with-slashes)

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need `cat` with `grep`.  That is enough:

```
x="$(grep ConfigPath /scratch/env.properties)"
```

Second, I believe this is not an assignment you want:

```
y=$(ConfigPath=/scratch/a/b)
```

If you want variable `y` to hold `ConfigPath=/scratch/a/b` string it should be:

```
y="ConfigPath=/scratch/a/b"
```

`$(...)` is a [command substitution in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

Third, you should use double quotes in `sed` command to make shell expand `x` and `y`:

```
sed "s/$x/$y/" env.properties
```

Also notice that `/` is a poor choice when working with Unix paths
because it is the delimiter. Use another character, for example
comma:

```
sed "s,$x,$y," env.properties
```

As noted by user
[Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda)
in the comment below you make this easier and better by using `sed` only and
making sure that `ConfigPath` is at the beginning of the line:

```
sed "s,^ConfigPath=.*$,ConfigPath=/scratch/a/b," env.properties
```

Comment: The `grep` step does not seem necessary. If you want to replace a line saying `ConfigPath=whatever`, you don't first have to `grep` for it.  Also, you may want to anchor the pattern in the `sed` expression, at least to the beginning of the line (or allow for blanks using e.g. `/^[[:blank:]]*ConfigPath=.*/`).

Comment: Thanks for input, I updated my answer. (BTW, I also use Dvorak layout)