# Sed shell script string with dollar not working

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I have two php file that will replaced by sed

first one is

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'demo',
    'password' => 'demopass',
    'database' => 'dbname'
);
```

I need to replace dbname to dynamic variables from shell script
I using this script and working

```
sed -i -e "/.*'database' =>*./ s/.*/'database' => '$1',/" /var/www/project/application/config/database.php
```

The second file is

```
$config['timezone'] = 'Asia/Jakarta';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'sess_project';
```

I need to change 'Asia/Jakarta' to another dynamic variables, but its not working since it has $ sign in the beginning.
this is my code

```
sed -i -e "/.*$config['timezone'] = *./ s/.*/$config['timezone'] = '$2';/" /var/www/project/application/config/config.php
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script)

Comment: I escape the $ using \ but still not working

Comment: In your expressions you use `*.`. Is this intentional or is it supposed to be `.*`?

Comment: @Kusalananda I think it was wrong, it supposed to be .*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually more interesting than it at first appears.

At least with GNU sed, it appears that `$` is only treated as a regular expression metacharacter when it appears at the end of a pattern. So for example whereas:

```
$ echo 'config$' | sed 's/config$/foobar$/'
config$
```

needs to be

```
$ echo 'config$' | sed 's/config\$/foobar$/'
foobar$
```

the `$` in

```
$ echo '$config' | sed 's/$config/$foobar/'
$foobar
```

works without escaping. **However**, because you've used weak (double) quotes around the sed expression to permit inclusion of literal single quotes, you need to escape the `$` in `$config` to prevent the **shell** expanding it (to a presumably empty value). Because it's the shell that's doing the expansion, it also needs to be escaped on the RHS of the replacement (where it wouldn't have been treated as a regex metacharacter).

On the other hand, `[` (which is **not** special to the shell when double quoted) **is** treated as a regex metacharacter regardless of position, and needs to be escaped for that reason - while `]` doesn't need to be escaped when it isn't preceded by (unescaped) `[`.

Finally, if the expansion of `$2` may contain a forward slash (like the `Asia/Jakarta` that it replaces), then that must also be escaped - or you must change the sed delimiter to a different character.

So given

```
$ cat config.php
$config['timezone'] = 'Asia/Jakarta';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'sess_project';
```

and

```
var='North America/Chicago'
```

then

```
$ sed -e "/.*\$config\['timezone'] = .*/ s/.*/\$config['timezone'] = '${var//\//\\\/}';/" config.php
$config['timezone'] = 'North America/Chicago';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'sess_project';
```

(note that I also corrected the presumed type `*.` to `.*`), or more simply

```
sed -e "/\$config\['timezone']/ s/=.*/= '${var//\//\\\/}';/" config.php
```

References:

1. [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script)
2. [Sed find and replace with slashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152817/sed-find-and-replace-with-slashes)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and this is working as expected. Yeah it's so tricky because I was mixed up shell and regex things

Answer (score 0):

Your sed seems overcomplicated. I suggest (assuming this script is called `t`):

```bsh
!/bin/bash
sed -i -e "s~\$config['timezone']\s*=\s*'.*';~\$config['timezone'] = '$1';~i" /var/www/project/application/config/config.php
```

And invoke it like this: `./t 'Asia/Novokuznetsk'`. Note that the slash is not escaped, due to regex delimiter `~`. The dollar signs are escaped, except in `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
repl_rhs=$(printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed -e 's:[\&/'\'']:\\&:g')
sed -e "
  /\(\$config[[]'timezone'] =\).*/s//\1 '$repl_rhs'/
" file.php
```

- escape the rhs metaharacters + s/// delimiter+ php single quoted string
- no newline in the replacement string $1