# sed: -e expression #3, char 59: unknown option to `s'

Tags: bash, sed

I am writing a script to replace three lines for input in a C++ code.This is the snippet of the C++ code whose inputs I want to change:

```
char outputFileName_ForBlueEdge[50] = "BlueEdge_SetA_PeriodRange1.dat"; //File with model parameters on the blue edge
    char outputFileName_ForPositiveGrowthModels[50] = "PostiveGrowth_SetA_PeriodRange1.dat"; //File with model parameters that have positve growth rates
    char log_directory_prefix[30] = "LOGS_A/LOGS_A"; //Prefix to log_directory, suffix is model number. This is where LINA file should be
```

And here is a minimal reproducible version of the bash script:

```
dir=$PWD
cplusplus_plotter="$dir"/BlueEdge_Plotter_V7.cpp

#Set B
  sed -i \
    -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*char outputFileName_ForBlueEdge[50]\).*/\1 = "BlueEdge_SetB_PeriodRange1.dat"/i" \
    -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*char outputFileName_ForPositiveGrowthModels[50]\).*/\1 = "PostiveGrowth_SetB_PeriodRange1.dat"/i" \
    -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*log_directory_prefix[30]\).*/\1 = "LOGS_B/LOGS_B"/i" \
    "$cplusplus_plotter"
```

However, the C++ file never changes and I keep getting the error:

```
sed: -e expression #3, char 59: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: You have a double quote conflict. Even the unix.stackexchange.com syntax highlighter make this clear here

Comment: Why are you using opening/closing double quotes ? If you're not on windows, use single quotes

Comment: Hi, I am using Ubuntu. I replaced the double quotes to singles such that BlueEdge_SetB_PeriodRange1.dat has just single quotes around it. I still get the error sed: -e expression #3, char 60: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Only opening/closing ones

Comment: Another issue is that you are using `/` as the sed pattern/replacement separator, but also have a `/` in the replacement text `LOGS_B/LOGS_B`. See for example [How to replace a string with a string containing slash with sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39800/how-to-replace-a-string-with-a-string-containing-slash-with-sed) (this is likely why it is complaining about *expression #3* specifically)

Comment: You have 4 / in the last sed command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
  sed -i \
    -e 's/^\([[:blank:]]*char outputFileName_ForBlueEdge\[50\]\).*/\1 = "BlueEdge_SetB_PeriodRange1.dat"/i' \
    -e 's/^\([[:blank:]]*char outputFileName_ForPositiveGrowthModels\[50\]\).*/\1 = "PostiveGrowth_SetB_PeriodRange1.dat"/i' \
    -e 's!^\([[:blank:]]*log_directory_prefix\[30\]\).*!\1 = "LOGS_B/LOGS_B"!i' \
    "$cplusplus_plotter"
```

You can choose the delimiter you want (in ascii table).

I choose `!` in last sed command, because you had 4 `/`.

Comment: I ran my bash script just using this command only. It is not changing the three lines.

Comment: Wut ??? oO Have you tested this ?

Comment: Yes, there are no errors, but the .cpp file remains the same.

Comment: I don't know the content of your file, I just help you to fix sed command...