# How to espace sequence of characters in sed?

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression, string

I am new to regex and running into some frustrations. I am trying to work with strings that express directories and am having the issue reproducible by running:

```
echo "a" | sed "s/a/home/books/examples/file/g"
```

I have tried escaping the replace part of the sed command by enclosing it in \Q and \E, as such:

```
echo "a" | sed "s/a/\Qhome/books/examples/file\E/g"
```

I have also tried to pass the -r flag in both commands to enable extended regex but I don't think that's the issue.

EDIT: I believe the issue is that sed interprets some of the characters i the path as special regex characters, therefore I wish to escape them but can't escape them one by one. The method of escaping the sequence I have described above did not work.

I am aware that it is possible to escape the individual characters but that doesn't work for me since many of these strings are accessed by variables, making such substitution require another similar sed command in itself!

I intend to execute this command inside a shell script.

Comment: [How to replace a string with a string containing slash with sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39800/how-to-replace-a-string-with-a-string-containing-slash-with-sed?)

Comment: [How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059/how-to-ensure-that-string-interpolated-into-sed-substitution-escapes-all-metac)

Comment: Is this a general ERE question? I found a link through boost for ERE that lists \Q & \E, but it appears it doesn't work. Maybe I have an older version? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html#id545376

Answer (score 0):

In sed, you have to manually backslash each character, or switch to different delimiters. If the string is dynamic and coming from a user, you never know which character will be safe. You can play with something like

```
s=${s//'\'/'\\'}
s=${s//'/'/'\/'}
sed "s/$s/replacement/g"
```

in bash, but switching to Perl is much easier. In Perl, you can use the `\Q...\E` syntax to quote a substring:

```
perl -pe 's/\Q$ARGV[1]\E/replacement/g' "$s"
```