# Finding and replacing text with sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to use **sed** to find a replace `"Host"` with `"Europe/London"`, however it is failing as shown below:

```
# sed -i -e 's/"Host"/"Europe/London"/g' /usr/local/php73/lib/php.ini
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace a string with a string containing slash with sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39800/how-to-replace-a-string-with-a-string-containing-slash-with-sed)

Answer (score 3):

Your replacement text contains `/`, which `sed` is treating as end-of-expression and then failing on the next character.

Either change the delimiter from `/` to something that doesn't appear in either the pattern match or its replacement text, or escape the character with a backslash:

```
s/"Host"/"Europe\/London"/g
s#"Host"#"Europe/London"#g
```