# How can I replace a string with a string that contains a special character, using sed

Tags: sed, special-characters

For example

replace

```
keystore=".
```

with

```
keystore="./
```

Comment: Is the special character in particular a problem? Do you know how you'd do that if it wasn't there?

Comment: [How to replace a string with a string containing slash with sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39800/how-to-replace-a-string-with-a-string-containing-slash-with-sed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace a string with a string containing slash with sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39800/how-to-replace-a-string-with-a-string-containing-slash-with-sed)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special character.
I take the assumption that the string is in the file `yourfile`

```
sed -i 's@keystore="\.@keystore="\./@' yourfile
```

More details about sed special character can be found here [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script)

Comment: You don't need to escape the dot in the replacement.