# double quote inside variable in Sed

Tags: sed

**Update**

Thanks @steeldriver for the answerd, the problem doesn't the double quote is the `/` only  i needeed remplace for `|`

Currently I have some problems with the `sed` command, I try to replace a string inside a file, the problem is the replace contains a double quote.

The variable contain the value of a file:
the variable text have this value

```
<string name="app_mod_app_crowdin_1">crowdin one es</string>
```

The problem is when execute the command `sed`

```
  sed -i .bak -e "Ns/.*/$text/" results.txt
```

error

```
sed: 1: "1s/.*/<string name="app ...": bad flag in substitute command: 's'
```

Comment: It's likely the forward slash in `$text` that's the problem - rather than the double quotes

Comment: ... see for example [How to replace a string with a string containing slash with sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39800/how-to-replace-a-string-with-a-string-containing-slash-with-sed)

Comment: omg you rigth! thanks @steeldriver

Comment: @steeldriver What if the `$text` string happens to contain a `|`? ... or `&`, or `\1`...

Answer (score 0):

```
foo='"hello world"'
echo $foo
"hello world"
echo '"hello world"' | sed 's/'"$foo"'/bye hell/'
bye hell
```

Comment: The quality of this answer could be improved by explaining the change (single quotes) instead of just demonstrating it. Also take note of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script

Answer (score 0):

Don't inject user-supplied data into a `sed` script.  It's more trouble than it's worth and could in many cases also be a security hole (especially with GNU `sed` which allows for arbitrary code execution).  Remember that injecting `$text` into the replacement part of a `s///` command actually modifies your `sed` script using whatever string `$text` is.

If you just need to change the first line to some fixed string, use `awk` instead:

```
cp results.txt results.txt.bak &&
awk -v value="$text" 'NR == 1 { $0 = value }; 1' results.txt.bak >results.txt
```

Testing:

```
$ text='<string name="app_mod_app_crowdin_1">crowdin one es</string>'
$ cat results.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
$ cp results.txt results.txt.bak && awk -v value="$text" 'NR == 1 { $0 = value }; 1' results.txt.bak >results.txt
$ cat results.txt
<string name="app_mod_app_crowdin_1">crowdin one es</string>
line 2
line 3
```

The `awk` code simply replaces the current line with the given text if `NR == 1`, i.e. if this is the first line of the file.  The trailing `1` causes all lines to be printed, whether modified or not.