# replacing part of find output in a readarray command

Tags: bash, sed, find

I need to create filelist (playlist) for using it in a Docker container. So the path of the file on the host system is not the mounting path. Now I try to fix this, but I have some trouble.

This is my script where I want to add the replacement

```
tdir="/mountingpoint"

readarray -d $'\0' listing < <(find "${fdir}"/*.mp3 -print0)
#for mixing up and write to file
listing=( $(shuf -e "${listing[@]}") )
printf "%s\n" "${listing[@]}" > "playlist.m3u"
```

A common way should be the use of `sed` but I have some trouble by putting things together.
I think I have to modify the script to something like `readarray -d $'\0' listing < <(find "${fdir}"/"${d}"/ -name "*.mp3" -print0 -exec sed -i "s/"$fdir"/"$tdir"/" {} \;)`
but this result in an error  `` sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s' ``
I think the slash in the dir name cause this error. But I also tried to replace the variables with a folder name to check the result, but nothing happened (beside a longer runtime). Nothing means no replacement in the output file.

I hope someone can handle my bad English and give me a hint what I do wrong.
Thanks a lot

Comment: The specific error is because you are trying to use `/` as the sed pattern delimiter but also have `/` in the pattern and replacement strings - see for example [How to replace a string with a string containing slash with sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39800/how-to-replace-a-string-with-a-string-containing-slash-with-sed). But there are other issues.

Comment: It would be best to experiment outside the readarray to get things working first. I **don't** think you want to use the `-exec` option to `find`, this is invoking sed on the files, not the file names. I think you want `find "${fdir}/${d}" -name \*.mp3 -print | sed "s=$fdir=$tdir=". I have dropped the -print0 which is good practice but currently confusing. Let us know how you get on and I can write up an answer if no one beats me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@icarus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/194382/icarus) has [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713733/replacing-part-of-find-output-in-a-readarray-command#comment1351937_713733), the `-exec` option doesn't make sense here - you want to apply your sed substitution to the null-delimited file*names*, using a sed pattern delimiter that is unlikely to be present in those names:

```
find "${fdir}/${d}" -name '*.mp3' -print0 | sed -z "s:$fdir:$tdir:"
```

IMHO there's no reason not to include the shuffle inside the pipeline as well:

```
find "${fdir}/${d}" -name '*.mp3' -print0 | sed -z "s:$fdir:$tdir:" | shuf -z
```

So for example given

```
~$ find . -name '*.mp3'
./dir/1.mp3
./dir/2.mp3
./dir/3.mp3
./dir/4.mp3
./dir/5.mp3
```

then

```
~$ fdir=./dir; tdir='./new/dir'

~$ readarray -t -d '' listing < <(find . -name '*.mp3' -print0 | sed -z "s:$fdir:$tdir:" | shuf -z)

~$ printf '%s\n' "${listing[@]}"
./new/dir/3.mp3
./new/dir/1.mp3
./new/dir/4.mp3
./new/dir/2.mp3
./new/dir/5.mp3
```

Comment: Works absolutely fine, and thanks a lot for the improvement of the shuffle. Nice to found a community kind and helpful like this. Thanks, I'm really happy now :-)

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
() {print -rC1 -- $tdir/$^@} $fdir/*.mp3(Noe['REPLY=$RANDOM']:t)
```

Or assuming neither `$fdir` nor `$tdir` contain `:` characters:

```
print -rC1 -- $fdir/*.mp3(Noe['REPLY=$RANDOM']:s:$fdir:$tdir)
```

With `bash` 4.4+ and GNU `shuf` (or `sort -zR`), you can always do:

```
print0()  { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }
println() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"; }

readarray -td '' listing < <(
  shopt -s nullglob
  cd -P -- "$fdir" && print0 *.mp3 | shuf -z)
println "${listing[@]/#/$tdir}"
```

Or:

```
print0()  { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }
println() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"; }

readarray -td '' listing < <(
  shopt -s nullglob
  print0 "$fdir"/*.mp3 | shuf -z)
println "${listing[@]/#"$fdir"/$tdir}"
```

as an equivalent.